# DistinctBy but ignore null/empty

Tags: c#, linq, morelinq

I have a list of movies, and I need to merge them with another list and duplicate.

I am using Jon Skeet's `DistinctBy(m => m.SomeUniqueMovieProperty)` to achieve this and it works OK. Except, we soon discovered that there would be cases where 10-20% of the movies (in either list) don't have this property filled out, causing `DistinctBy` to collapse them into 1 lucky movie.

This is a problem, we want to keep all those movies that don't have a value for this property. Initially I thought of extracting these movies from each collection, duplicating, then merging them again, is there a shorter solution to this problem?

Comment: I'd follow your choice. Filter out the ones will null property value, run distinct by on it and then merge it with the filtered ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concatenate the results of `DistinctBy()` with the results of `Where([null or empty]).`

```
var nullMovies = allMovies.Where(m=>string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.SomeUniqueMovieProperty));

var distinctNonNullMovies = allMovies.Where(m => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.SomeUniqueMovieProperty)).DistinctBy(m => m.SomeUniqueMovieProperty);

var result = nullMovies.Concat(distinctNonNullMovies);
```

Comment: We may have empty values for this property, so this solution would take the cake. Scott's solution can be made to work with ? but becomes less readable. +1 to his solution as well, could work in another case

Comment: The one drawback of this solution is it will cause multiple enumerations of `allMovies`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to include all of the nulls you need to replace the null property with something that is unique when it is null. Assuming the property is a string a Guid will do nicely for this job.

```
.DistinctBy(m => m.SomeUniqueMovieProperty ?? Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
```

Any time it hits a property with a null value it will be filled in with a random new guid value.

---

If you want to also have empty titles not get removed change the query to

```
.DistinctBy(m => String.IsNullOrEmpty(m.SomeUniqueMovieProperty) ? Guid.NewGuid().ToString() : m.SomeUniqueMovieProperty)
```

---

Another option is make your own `DistinctBy` that behaves the way you want. This is a tweaked version of the [original source](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs) that only applies the filter if `shouldApplyFilter` returns true, comments are also removed for brevity.

```
static partial class MoreEnumerable
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> ConditionalDistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, Func<TKey, bool> shouldApplyFilter)
    {
        return source.ConditionalDistinctBy(keySelector, shouldApplyFilter, null);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<TSource> ConditionalDistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, Func<TKey, bool> shouldApplyFilter, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        if (keySelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("keySelector");
        if (shouldApplyFilter == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("shouldApplyFilter");
        return ConditionalDistinctByImpl(source, keySelector, shouldApplyFilter, comparer);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<TSource> ConditionalDistinctByImpl<TSource, TKey>(IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, Func<TKey, bool> shouldApplyFilter, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        var knownKeys = new HashSet<TKey>(comparer);
        foreach (var element in source)
        {
            var key = keySelector(element);
            if (shouldApplyFilter(key) && knownKeys.Add(key))
            {
                yield return element;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It would be used like

```
.ConditionalDistinctBy(m => m.SomeUniqueMovieProperty, s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s));
```

Comment: You're completely ignoring the cases when SomeUniqueMovieProperty equals a string representation of a random number ;)

Comment: If the property can predict a Guid generated by `Guid.NewGuid()` I think it deserves to be filtered out, it is too dangerous, it's psychic ;)

Comment: Not to pick nits, just want to remind the op does say null/empty in title

Comment: @MrAnderson and I think the title could be interfered as "DistinctBy but ignore null/empty and just include all of them instead"

Comment: @MrAnderson also, I advise you stay away from gaming.stackexechange.com if [all you look at are titles](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/2196/3638) :)

Comment: @FailedUnitTest It comes down to whether you want to count only nulls as distinct, or also empty string ("").

Comment: @MrAnderson OH, I see now. I am updating the answer.

Comment: @FailedUnitTest see my updated answer, I created a new extension method that makes it clean to read and only does a single enumeration of the list.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `m`'s `Equals`/`GetHashCode` isn't overridden, if `m.SomeUniqueMovieProperty` is `null` and you don't have any other unique key, you can use `m` itself as the unique key.

```
DistinctBy(m => (object) m.SomeUniqueMovieProperty ?? m)
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could filter them on a composite distinct key, like as follows

```
movies.DistinctBy(m => String.Format({0}{1}{...},m.prop1,m.prop2,[]));
```

Comment: + 1 Interesting thought, unfortunately that property is the only one reliable enough to determine uniqueness. If you call that reliable ;)

Answer (score 1):

One last way, which is probably overkill, you can implement IEqualityComparer and put the logic in there if null is consider unique.  DistinctBy has an overload for just this case.

```
public class MovieComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{

    public bool Equals(string x, string y)
    {
        if (x == null || y == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return x == y;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it allowed for an `IEqualityComparer` to make `Equals(x, x)` return `false` for any `x`? [The documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132154%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states: "The Equals method is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive. That is, it returns true if used to compare an object with itself [...]"

Comment: If this was some class other than `string` make sure you are careful with `x == y`, you may want to use `Object.Equals(x,y)` instead.

Comment: @hvd since this is a unique case where they want the same value to be treated as unique, I believe it's allowed.  I wouldn't do this for a generic comparison which is why it would be it's own class with it's own comments when to use.

Comment: @CharlesNRice I updated my comment, doing so contradicts the spec, and implementing interfaces in a way that contradicts the spec, while using those implementations with *any* core .NET Framework method, typically effectively leads to undefined behaviour.